# Reflection invoke método de una propiedad de tipo list

Tags: c#, reflection

El escenario es el siguiente:

La clase RMGList hereda de List, contiene una serie de métodos, en este caso quiero llamar mediante reflection el método ObtenerEntidadesAñadidas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase Cliente hereda de Entidad que es una clase abstracta y tiene una propiedad llamada direcciones que es del tipo RMGList de Dirección.

¿Cómo puedo hacer un invoke del método ObtenerEntidadesAñadidas mediante reflection?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

private void Guardar(Entidad entidad)

```
    {

        foreach (PropertyInfo pInfo in entidad.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
        {
            foreach (MethodInfo mInfo in pInfo.PropertyType.GetRuntimeMethods())
            {
                if (mInfo.Name == "MoverEntidadesAñadidas")
                {                        
                    mInfo.Invoke(??? , new object[] { null } );
                }
            } 
        }            
    }
```

Guardar recibe una entidad del tipo Entidad. Me recorro todas las propiedades de la entidad recibida y por cada entidad sus métodos. Si encuentro el método que estoy buscando quiero ejecutarlo. En este caso el método no recibe parámetros.

El primer parámetro de tipo Object de invoke no sé que debo pasarle.
Gracias por vuestras respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías pasarle como primer argumento una instancia de la clase a la cual pertenece el método que deseas invocar. En este caso, por tanto, deberías pasarle un objeto del tipo RMGList.